# Activity restarts my game on screen rotation (Android)

Tags: android, layout, orientation, oncreate

I know this question was already asked, but mine is a little different:

I have 2 different layout files for my game; one for portrait mode and one for landscape. When  I rotate the screen, the onCreate method restarts my game (creates all the elements again). I don´t want this to happen, so I wrote this line in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

It works, onCreate is not called, but the new layout is not being showed properly!

I tried to put the following code in my Activity, but it just keeps doing weird things:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.gameview);
}
```

how can I fix this?
thanx guys

Comment: You need save and restore value when change screen mode. [See here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Comment: Thank you, but I just can't save ALL the things I created in a bundle... I have several objects and stuff. Everything has to be re-created every time someone rotates the screen??

Comment: you can put those stuff in your application object, and access them from your activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all understand how orientation changing in android works:

1. By default activity restarts on orientation changed event (and goes throw `onCreate`).
2. If you write `android:configChanges="orientation"` in manifest - it means it will not be recreated, but just remeasure and redraw view tree.

Comments about your code:

- If you have different layout for different orientations - you have to recreate activity on orientation changed.
- Method `setContentView` should called just once per activity lifecycle.

General way to handle this situation is:

1. Save game state in method `onSaveInstanceState`
2. In `onCreate` method restore game state if it is supplied (`savedInstanceState` param is not null).
3. Remove listening of configuration changing from manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You should use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() for save state and for restore state getLastNonConfigurationInstance() for any objects. Or hard-code set android:screenOrientation="portrait/landscape" in manifest.