# In Android I m trying to call 2 xml layout in single Activity for different orientation

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In Android I m trying to call 2 xml layout in single Activity for different orientation ,it works but when orientation changes from landscape to portrait my activity is getting reloaded,but i wanted how it was before changing the orientation

please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Activity restarts my game on screen rotation (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505094/activity-restarts-my-game-on-screen-rotation-android)

Answer (score 1):

You mean to say you want to save the state of your activity .You can save your values in onBundleSaveinstance method as key value pair and simply get it in oncreate and set the values again . Eg. save your check box state as checked or not checked asa boolean.

Comment: Is there any way to Save the sate of Activity in onsavedInstanceState not the values

Comment: Whole Activity object you cant save . But in onsaveinstance you have permission of saving only string key value pairs  so to retrieve custom objects back there is another nice methods i.e. onRetainConfigurationInstancestate .. look below example for reference http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid your `onCreate()` method getting called every time you do an orientation, add this to your Manifest. `<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />`

Which will not reload your view, and what was there before will still remain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I define it in manifest file when orientation happens second xml is not getting reloaded

Comment: My bad, that's true. It won call onCreate() so you second view won't be reloaded.

Comment: You should do what Deepak Sharma suggested.